# Let $U\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ be defined by the basis set $B=\{[1,1,1]^T,[1,-1,1]^T\}$. Formulate a system of equations to find the...

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, orthogonality

orthogonal complementary subspace $W$ of $U$. Use the orthogonality of $U$ and $W$ to propose a fast method to express the vector $[2,2,1]^T$ as a sum of vectors from these complementary subspaces.

Let $B_W=[b_1,b_2,b_3]^T$ be the orthogonal complementary subspace of $B$. In order for me to find it, each of the spaces must be orthogonal to eachtoher, therefore the dot product between them must be $0$: $$[1,1,1]^T\cdot[b_1,b_2,b_3]^T=0\longrightarrow1\cdot b_1+1\cdot b_2+1\cdot b_3=0$$ for the first basis vector of $B$ and $$[1,-1,1]^T\cdot[b_1,b_2,b_3]^T=0\longrightarrow1\cdot b_1-1\cdot b_2+1\cdot b_3=0$$ for the second basis vector of $B$. But this gives me a system of equations of 2 equations and 3 unknowns, I am not sure where I can get the third equation. The last condition I know for $B_W$ to be an orthogonal complementary subspace of $B$ is that the union of the two basis sets must form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I am not sure how to do the second part of the problem either, but I think once I get the first part I can attempt the second one too, so I just need a hint, thanks.

**SOURCE**: Linear Algebra and Optimization for Machine Learning: A Textbook (page 63, problem 2.3.4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a third equation. The subspace you're looking for has dimension $1$, so it has infinitely many vectors. In other words, your system of equations must be indeterminate.

For solving the system, if you add both equations you'll get
$$2b_1+2b_3=0\Longrightarrow b_3=-b_1.$$
And substituting in any of the two equations, you can see that $b_2=0$. So your subspace is
$$W=\big\{[b_1,0,-b_1]^T:\ b_1\in\mathbb{R}\big\}=\big\langle[1,0,-1]^T\big\rangle.$$

For the second question, suppose that $\vec v=[2,2,1]^T=\vec u+\vec w$, with $\vec u\in U$ and $\vec w=b[1,0,-1]^T\in W$. Then
$$[2,2,1]^T\cdot[1,0,-1]^T=\underbrace{\vec u\cdot[1,0,-1]^T}_0+b[1,0,-1]^T\cdot[1,0,-1]^T\Longrightarrow$$
$$\Longrightarrow1=2b\Longrightarrow b=\frac{1}{2}.$$
So you have
$$\vec w=\frac{1}{2}[1,0,-1]^T=\left[\frac{1}{2},0,-\frac{1}{2}\right]^T\in W;$$
$$\vec u=[2,2,1]^T-\left[\frac{1}{2},0,-\frac{1}{2}\right]^T=\left[\frac{3}{2},2,\frac{3}{2}\right]^T.$$